# DataTemplate to populate the content of other DataTemplate

Tags: wpf

I've like 'base' DataTemplate that contains TabControl with 3 tabs. In each tab I put empty ContentPresenter.
I want to write new DataTemplate for each derived type. In which, I want to populate the all 3 ContentPresenter.
How can I reffer to each ContentPresenter of the base template so I can put data inside?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have set content of each tabitem.
If the content objects have different types you just have to make a datatemplate for each of the types.

Comment: My problem is that content object in 3 tabs is the same one. And I want to write only one DataTemplate in each derived type....

Comment: I am not quite sure what it is you want - but you could have a property on your object with a collection - and each item in the collection could correspond to a tab. Tabcontrol is an itemscontrol so you can set the itemssource.